# Why does the BIMI authentication result header show results for icloud.com instead of the company domain?

Tags: email, bimi

I've received an email from my bank (bank.example.com) that has an expired VMC certificate. Understandably, this causes the BIMI logo fail to display in my iOS mail client (with iCloud as my mail hosting provider)

Now when I inspect the headers of the email, I see this:

```
Authentication-Results: bimi.icloud.com; bimi=fail reason="invalid certificate"
```

Why is the domain bimi.icloud.com being checked for BIMI ?
Shouldn't the domain be the bank domain instead?

```
//What I expected it to be
Authentication-Results: bank.example.com; bimi=fail reason="invalid certificate"
```

I've also noticed this with other BIMI compliant emails which show the logo. The authentication results always are for bimi.icloud.com instead of the original company domain